# How do asset and entry urls in rich text fields change with the environment?

Tags: richtext, multi-environment

If I have a rich text field containing a link to an asset and I create the link on my development server `sample.craft.dev`, the html in the rich text field contains this:

```
<a href="http://sample.craft.dev/uploads/pdfs/file.pdf#asset:945:url">the file</a>
```

If I then move the database to my staging server `stage.sample.com`, the html in the rich text field now magically contains the new url:

```
<a href="http://stage.sample.com/uploads/pdfs/file.pdf#asset:945:url">the file</a>
```

How does that happen?

If the html in the rich text field on the development server instead contains this:

```
<select class="jumpMenu js_jumpMenu">
  <option value="">-- select brochure --</option>
  <option value="http://stage.sample.com/uploads/pdfs/file.pdf#asset:969:url">The File</option>
</select>
```

Then the url is not rewritten. Why is that?

Comment: I assume you're manually entering the `#asset:969:url` in the 2nd example?

Comment: Yes, entering it manually.

Comment: Not an answer, but take a look at RichTextInput.js. There is some magic going on in there specifically when linking to an asset or inserting an image.